# Threads won't start fire and forget

Tags: java, multithreading

So I am trying to get a number of threads to start and run on their own without intervention in java.

The Threads are made by extending the thread class like so:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
public void run(){
    executeEvents();
}
```

executeEvents has a bunch of business logic inside.

However before this is called the threads are made like such:

```
public MyThread(int threadNumber, ArrayList<Event> events, Mailbox mailbox){
    this.events = events;
    this.mailbox = mailbox;
    this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
}
```

and in the main there is an array of these threads created and then supposedly should be started

```
    public static void spawnThreads(int numOfThreads){
    Mailbox mailbox = new Mailbox(numOfThreads);
    MyThread[] threads = new MyThread[numOfThreads];
    ArrayList<Event> events = spawnEvents(numOfThreads*10,numOfThreads);
    ArrayList<Event>[] eventsForThread = new ArrayList[numOfThreads];
    Random rng = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < eventsForThread.length; i++){
        eventsForThread[i] = new ArrayList<Event>();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < events.size(); i++){
        eventsForThread[rng.nextInt(numOfThreads)].add(events.get(i));
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++){
        threads[i] = new MyThread();
        threads[i].start();
        threads[i].addToMyThread(i,eventsForThread[i],mailbox);
        threads[i].executeEvents();
    }
   // executeEvents(threads,mailbox);
}
```

However for some reason when this runs the threads do not start in parrallel but in order and I can't figure out why.

I can see that it isn't running in parallel because each event inside the arraylist has a randomised wait

```
public void executeEvent(){
    try {
        Random rng2 = new Random(); 
        Thread.sleep(rng2.nextInt(400));
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Event.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }
```

(This is inside the `Event` class)

So they should not be finishing in order.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the [`Thread#start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) method instead of `Thread#run()`. The latter does not spawn the thread to be run in parallel:

```
for(int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++){
    threads[i] = new Thread(new MyThread(i,eventsForThread[i],mailbox));
    threads[i].start();
}
```

From the Javadocs of the `start` method:

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the `run` method of this thread.
>
> The result is that two threads are *running concurrently*: the current thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and the other thread (which executes its run method).

**Update:**

After the updated question, it seems the problem is with the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++){
    threads[i] = new MyThread();
    threads[i].start();
    threads[i].addToMyThread(i,eventsForThread[i],mailbox);
    threads[i].executeEvents(); // this is causing the serial execution
}
```

The method `start()` will spawn a new thread, but right after that you call `threads[i].executeEvents()` which blocks until it returns. This is not how it should be implemented. The `start` method already calls the `run` method of `MyThread` which in turn calls `executeEvents`. You only need to call `start`. And the part that "adds" the events to the thread should be before this call, something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++){
    threads[i] = new MyThread();
    threads[i].addToMyThread(i,eventsForThread[i],mailbox);
    threads[i].start();  // this will call executeEvents in a separate thread
}
```

Comment: When I do it like that it seems like nothing occurs after that for the individual threads, and the outputs I was getting before now don't even show at all

Comment: Also note that `MyThread` is used as a `Runnable` for another `Thread` that is actually started.

Comment: @user1742032 Are you sure about that? Did you try to debug the `spawnThreads` method? Or add some logging to trace its execution?

Comment: @manouti I'm very sure that it's executing in series because part of the business logic for the execution includes sleeps of around 300ms +  multiple times (and it is randomised) meaning that it is not possible that on every run the threads would finish in order.

I also tried changing the constructor for the class to empty, running start and then inputing the variables that need to be added to each thread, but afterwards any event calls do not happy in parallel

Comment: @user1742032 I think you should post this information in the question.

Comment: Look into using an ExecutorService with invokeAll.

Comment: @manouti Implemented your change, and nothing comes out, however, the moment I remove a call to Thread.sleep that is in the code... it works... sometimes...